# Interchange of limiting operations (question from an engineer)

Tags: limits, derivatives, summation

I need to clarify when are the below operations valid. If possible, please link me to the related theorems, where I can find details.

1- Given a double integral 
\begin{equation}
\int_{X}\int_Y f(x,y) \:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Under what conditions on $f$ the interchange of the order of integration is valid so that
\begin{equation}
\int_{X}\int_Y f(x,y)\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}x = \int_{Y}\int_X f(x,y)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}
A related question here, is when we have, instead of a double integral, one integral and infinite sum. For example 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} h(n) \int f(x)g(n) \:\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
where $n$ is integer, and $x\in \mathbb{R}$. When is the following valid?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} h(n) \int_X f(x)g(n) \:\mathrm{d}x = \int_X  f(x) \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} h(n)g(n)\right) \:\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

2- Under what conditions on the integrand, the interchange of the derivative and integral signs is vaild. For example, 
when can we say that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\iint_S u(x,y,t) \:\mathrm{d}x \:\mathrm{d}y\right)= \iint_S \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,y,t) \:\mathrm{d}x \:\mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}

Comment: For #1, see Fubini-Tonelli theorems, and for #2 you need the Dominated Convergence theorem. For the latter, See "Introduction to Measure Theory" by R. Bartle - it has a nice section titled "Dependence on a parameter".

Comment: Thank you Prahlad. Would you state what you can remember regarding the weakest conditions under which we can do the interchange? Also,  what is the difference between the double integral, and the infinite sum and integral cases? I once came across the following statement: We can interchange the infinite sum with the integral since the series is uniformly convergent. In general, regarding my question above, I have difficulty in having a clear structure in my mind of the results.